# using sprites as a healthbar

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Recently, I finally managed to implement a working health bar w/ I-frames between each hit. However, it looked untidy as all I had used for the health bar was a single red line drawn by pygame. Instead of this I had hoped to use hearts which reduced by half a heart each time the player gets hit.

My question is; how do I get the health bar to update when my health goes past a certain point? Every method that I try doesn’t seem to work.

My working code is below;

## Game class

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from player import Player
from enemy import Enemy


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')

# Spawn player

player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)


# Spawn enemy

enemy = Enemy(150, 150)
enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_sprites.add(enemy)


healthbar = HealthBar.Health_Bar(10, 10)
health_bar = pygame.sprite.Group()
health_bar.add(healthbar)




clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False


# ----- Event Loop

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)


# ----- Game Logic

    all_sprites_list.update()
    enemy_sprites.update(player)

    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_sprites, False)

    for hit in player_hit_list:
       player.hit_check(1)

       if player.is_dead():
           done = True



    screen.fill(WHITE)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    enemy_sprites.draw(screen)
    health_bar.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

## Player class

```
from constants import *
import pygame
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.health = 10
        self.invincible_until = datetime.now()


        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y



# I-frames for when taking damage

# ---

    def can_take_damage(self):

        if datetime.now() < self.invincible_until:
            return False

        return True


    def hit_check(self, damage):

        if self.can_take_damage():
            self.health -= damage
            self.invincible_until = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds = .5)


    def is_dead(self):

        return self.health <= 0
```

## Enemy class

```
from constants import *
import pygame

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

## Health bar class

```
import pygame
import constants
from Spritesheet import SpriteSheet



class Health_Bar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        health_frames = []

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("full_heart.png")

        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 40)
        health_frames.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 30)
        health_frames.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 20)
        health_frames.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 10, 30)
        health_frames.append(image)

        self.image = health_frames[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

    def update(self):

        if player.health <= 5:
            self.image = health_frames[1]
```

## SpriteSheet class

```
import pygame
import constants

class SpriteSheet(object):

    def __init__(self, file_name):

        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()


    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):

        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        image.set_colorkey(constants.BLACK)

        return image
```

Constants class just defines a few colours

Below are the hearts used for the health bar (I only have 2 stages of the health bar for simplicity in the example)

[image]

[image]

Thankyou for any help provided!!

Comment: I don't see your current code actually drawing the health sprites?

Comment: at the end of the game class code I have the line `player.health_bar(player.image, 10, 10)` which is a modification of the code I used to draw the rectangle health bar on the screen previously. Like I said this just draws the sprite over my player.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I didn't realize `health_bar` replaces `self.image`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (the healthbar stays in the top left corner). Please post a [minimal, complete and **verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to edit the question itself, I updated it so that the health bar was it’s own class like AKX suggested but it doesn’t seem to be able to update when my health goes past a certain point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the `update` method of the `health_bar` group or of the `healthbar` sprite when the player takes damage (or call it every frame), so that it can change the `self.image` to `self.health_frames[1]`.

Also, the `health_frames` list must be an attribute or you won't be able to access it in the `update` method.

```
class Health_Bar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("full_heart.png")
        self.health_frames = [
            sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 40),
            sprite_sheet.get_image(0, 0, 40, 30),
            ]
        self.image = self.health_frames[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))

    def update(self):
        if player.health <= 5:
            self.image = self.health_frames[1]
```

Comment: Oh of course, I’m not sure how I missed that I didn’t call the update method - thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Drawing a health bar should be considered altogether separate from drawing the player character. (Ditto with drawing other GUI like score, kills, what-have-you).

You should do GUI drawing (usually) at the end of your frame render code, so it gets drawn on top of everything else.

Comment: Ive changed the question with my edits so that the health_bar no longer replaces self.image. However, when i try to update the sprite nothing seems to work; I tried in the Health Bar class to update it so that when player.health drops below 5 it moves to the next sprite in the group but it doesnt seem to work